# Retrieve the numbers from the file corresponding to the given regions specified in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The below is my dataframe :

```
 Sno       Name    Region         Num
0    1      Rubin    Indore  79744001550
1    2      Rahul     Delhi  89824304549
2    3      Rohit     Noida  91611611478
3    4     Chirag     Delhi  85879761557
4    5       Shan    Bharat  95604535786
5    6      Jordi    Russia  80777784005
6    7         El    Russia  70008700104
7    8       Nino     Spain  87707101233
8    9       Mark       USA  98271377772
9   10  Pattinson  Hawk Eye  87888888889
```

Retrieve the numbers and store it region wise from the given CSV file.

```
delhi_list = []

for i in range(len(data)):
   if data.loc[i]['Region'] == 'Delhi':
     delhi_list.append(data.loc[i]['Num'])

delhi_list = []

for i in range(len(data)):
   if data.loc[i]['Region'] == 'Delhi':
     delhi_list.append(data.loc[i]['Num'])
```

I am getting the results, but I want to achieve the data by the use of dictionary in python. Can I use it?

Comment: Is this what you need...? `data.groupby('Region')['Num'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Comment: Yes, Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), apply the `list` aggregation then use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
data.groupby('Region')['Num'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

[out]

```
{'Bharat': [95604535786],
 'Delhi': [89824304549, 85879761557],
 'Hawk Eye': [87888888889],
 'Indore': [79744001550],
 'Noida': [91611611478],
 'Russia': [80777784005, 70008700104],
 'Spain': [87707101233],
 'USA': [98271377772]}
```